# Is it possible to write the result of code transformations back to the original source files?

Tags: frama-c

I would like to perform code transformations on **multiple** files and write the changes that result from these transformations back, ideally the original files. For example, I would like to add an if-Statement to a function `funcA` that originates from file `fileA.c` and a function `funcB` that is defined in file `fileB.c`. After performing transformations on `funcA` and `funcB`, I would like to overwrite files `fileA.c` and `fileB.c` with the resulting source code. I do not necessarily need the source code before macro expansions (I suspect this would not be possible).

Is there a sensible way of doing this using Frama-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can do it *for a single file* by simply writing the output to a file (with options `-print` and `-ocode <file>`), as in:

```
frama-c file.c [add your transformation options here] -print -ocode file.c
```

This will work because Frama-C reads input source files to parse them and build its AST before actually writing the output. So, by the time it truncates the original file to start overwriting it, the file has already been entirely read.

Note that, strictly speaking, this behavior could change in the future (in other words, this is *not* a recommended way to use Frama-C, although it should work in practice).

**However**, for **multiple** files, this is not currently possible: Frama-C always merges them all in a single, unified AST, before further processing. While the AST elements do retain location information about which source file they come from, there is currently nothing that tells the pretty-printer to output each part to a different file.

Note that, in general, this is somewhat complex: C allows multiple declarations of globals, so you can have a file `a.c` declaring a `struct st;` without specifying its fields, then another file `b.c` which actually declares its fields; when pretty-printing these files, you'd need to remember all the original declarations. And depending on the kind of syntactic changes that were performed, these might impact some of the declarations, but not all.

Overall, I believe it is theoretically *possible* to somehow tell Frama-C to remember all of those details and try to use location information to pretty-print its AST to multiple files (and if we include logic preprocessing, with ACSL annotations and such, I'm not even sure that is doable), but it would require *deep* changes to the kernel.

Therefore, currently, I'd say that there is no sensible way to tell Frama-C to do it, at least in the general case. For some specific subtasks related to that (e.g., pretty-printing a few select globals), it is possible to create an AST visitor that, when visiting such elements, pretty-prints them to a file whose name is related to the original name (e.g., for an AST node whose location is `f.c`, print it to `f-out.c`). But ensuring that such files are syntactically valid C in *all* cases makes it much more complex. And it would require at least writing a decent amount of OCaml code for a script.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention some vital information about my use case in my question. I changed it accordingly